# Reading arff file into R throws up exception

Tags: r, weka, arff

i am new to R.

```
read.arff(file = "/Users/macbookpro/loving_eval_stem_stop_train.arff")
```

I am running this piece of code and it seems to give me this exception

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '{21'
```

I am sure my absolute file path is correct. I have no issues reading the file into weka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you have posted, I suspect that this is a sparse format ARFF file. I am not sure about what package you are using to read the arff file into R, but it may not support sparse format.

You can try converting into a full format arff file with weka. (It will probably increase the file size, but it should become R readable.)

You can use this command to perform the operation

```
java weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.SparseToNonSparse -i <input_file> -o <output_file> -c <index of class attribute>
```

Comment: You may want to look at the rweka package. [http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html]